# Please help me it's about Gta

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, grand-theft-auto-online

So I have Gta online on 360 and I'm buying Xbox one, but I don't want to joim my 360 on to my Xbox one I want to make a new account on Xbox one. Am I able to buy Gta on Xbox one then transfer data from  social  club without joining my Xbox 360 account with Xbox one but to just login to rockstar social club instead? Plsss help!!

Answer (score 2):

This information is taken directly from the [Rockstar Games Support](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202892778-Transferring-Your-Previous-Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-Characters-and-Progression-to-PlayStation-4-Xbox-One-or-PC):

> Transferring to Xbox One
>
> What you need:

1. A copy of Grand Theft Auto V on Xbox One.
2. Previous Grand Theft Auto Online character and progression data on either Xbox 360 or PlayStation®3.

   **Note**: When transferring from Xbox 360 to Xbox One you
   must use the same Gamertag. A new Gamertag on Xbox One cannot be
   transferred to from a different Gamertag on Xbox 360 since your
   character’s progress is tied to the Gamertag.
3. A Rockstar Games Social Club account. If you do not already have a Social Club account, you will need to create one. Click [here](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202892778-Transferring-Your-Previous-Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-Characters-and-Progression-to-PlayStation-4-Xbox-One-or-PC#CreateSocialClubAccount) for info on creating an account.
4. An Xbox Live Gold account.

If transferring from Xbox 360, your Social Club account will need to be linked to the Xbox Live account used to play GTA Online on both systems. 
If transferring from PlayStation®3,your Social Club account will need to be linked to the PlayStation®Network account used while playing GTA Online on
PlayStation®3 and the Xbox Live account used to play GTA Online on
Xbox One. 
If you still need to link your Social Club account to your console account(s), please click [here](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202892778-Transferring-Your-Previous-Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-Characters-and-Progression-to-PlayStation-4-Xbox-One-or-PC#LinkAccounts) for more information.

How to transfer your previous Grand Theft Auto Online character and progression data to Xbox One:

1. Start Grand Theft Auto V on Xbox One and log into Xbox Live.
2. Enter GTA Online via the Character Select Wheel or the Pause Menu.
3. You will be given the option to transfer your previous GTA Online character and progression data, along with the opportunity to change your character’s appearance again. If you wish to complete the transfer later, you can return to this option via the Online section of the Pause Menu.
4. Once you have chosen to transfer your previous character and progression data, the transferrable in-game money, RP and Rank of all previous characters will be displayed. These are the characters that will be transferred to Xbox One. If you have previous character and progression data on both Xbox 360 and PlayStation®3, you will be prompted to select one set of data. You can only transfer one set of character and progression data for your Xbox Live account on Xbox One.
5. Once the transfer has completed, you will be prompted to choose a character and enter GTA Online.

**Please note**:

> Any existing Xbox One GTA Online character and progression data will
>   be replaced by your previous character and progression data during the
>   transfer, except for any existing in-game money, which will be
>   combined with your transferred balance.
>
> All earned in-game money will transfer. Purchased in-game money that
>   has not yet been spent will only transfer within a console family (e.g.
>   Xbox 360 to Xbox One).
>
> You
>   will still be able to play with your existing characters on Xbox 360
>   and/or PlayStation®3, however any progress made with versions of the
>   characters on those systems after a transfer will remain on the those
>   systems only. You can only transfer a set of character and progression
>   data from PlayStation®3 or Xbox 360 once.

Comment: So, to actually answer the question: no, you can't transfer it to a different gamertag.

Comment: okay thank you! So to do this I have to join my 360 into Xbox one like my account into it for this to happen

Comment: @Jay That's correct, yes. You have to integrate your account into the newly bought Xbox One.